# How treat information in table view that have Nested Header?

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to set information in the table view that has a Nested Header, just like Excel table. But I spend hours without get anything that can help me

The result that I need is like this:

[image]

But is currently just looks like this:

[image: I can't see all information]

My code to set information in the table :

```
JourSuivi j1=new JourSuivi(1, "30/04/2016", 23, 34, new ArrayList<>(), 43, new ArrayList<>(), 345, 23, 2, new ArrayList<>(), 11);
JourSuivi j2=new JourSuivi(1, "30/04/2016", 23, 34, new ArrayList<>(), 43, new ArrayList<>(), 345, 23, 2, new ArrayList<>(), 11);
List<Tonnage>ls=new ArrayList<>();
ls.add(new Tonnage(ls_ton,"ONCF",33));

j1.setNbWgs(ls);j2.setNbWgs(ls);
List<Double> ls_d=new ArrayList<>();
ls_d.add(12.33);ls_d.add(44.2);

j2.setTocpSA(ls_d);j1.setToncf(ls_d);j1.setToncf(ls_d);j2.setToncf(ls_d);
ObservableList<JourSuivi> data=FXCollections.observableArrayList(j1,j2);
table.getColumns().addAll(datecol, expeditionCol,numTrainCol,nWgsCol,totalcol,toncf,totaloncf,nTraincol,tocp,cumul);
controller.getHb().getChildren().add(table);
//chargement des données
table.setItems(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think i really understand the question, but this might help :

```
@FXML
TableView<String> tblView; // your table view here

TableColumn<String, String> columnMain = new TableColumn<>();
columnMain.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("someValue"));
columnMain.setText("some text");

TableColumn<String, String> columnChild1 = new TableColumn<>();
columnChild1 .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("someValue"));
columnChild1 .setText("some text");

TableColumn<String, String> columnChild2 = new TableColumn<>();
columnChild2 .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("someValue"));
columnChild2 .setText("some text");

columnMain.getColumns().add(columnChild1);
columnMain.getColumns().add(columnChild2);

// columnMain now has two child columns columnChild1 and columnChild2

tblView.getColumns().add(columnMain);
```

if you want to reach columnChild1 :

```
tblView.getColumns().get(0).getColumns().get(0);
```

if you want to reach columnChild2 :

```
tblView.getColumns().get(0).getColumns().get(1);
```

**edit :**

if you want to fill the table with data , this is the best way for me -> create a class to fill the table with , ex :

the table :

```
@FXML
TableView<Person> tblView;

TableColumn<String, String> columnMain = new TableColumn<>();
columnMain.setText("Name");

TableColumn<String, String> columnChild1 = new TableColumn<>();
columnChild1 .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
columnChild1 .setText("First Name");

TableColumn<String, String> columnChild2 = new TableColumn<>();
columnChild2 .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
columnChild2 .setText("Last Name");

columnMain.getColumns().add(columnChild1);
columnMain.getColumns().add(columnChild2);

// columnMain now has two child columns columnChild1 and columnChild2

tblView.getColumns().add(columnMain);
```

and the object :

```
public class Person{
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      public Person(String firstName,String lastName){
            this.firstName=firstName;
            this.lastName=lastName;
     }
}
```

fill the table :

```
ArrayList<Person> tableData = new ArrayList<>();
tableData.add(new Person("Elhassani","Ayoub"));
tableData.add(new Person("Abdullah","Asendar"));
tblView.getitems().addAll(tableData);
```

Comment: thank u very match .but it stell not work  . in fact i want to set informations in the table , and i use the code below but i don't see data in the table .

Comment: ObservableList<String> ob=FXCollections.observableArrayList("gagga","bbbd","hdgdgd");
  tblView.setItems(ob);

Comment: but it stell not showing : demo_Result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ypM7u2WIySSk1PekdrbjJhRms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElhassaniAyoub glad it helped )))